# Receiving nil for UIElements inside tableViewCell added via storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a `TableViewCell` entirely in storyboard just as I have in any other app. I want to set the properties however the components inside of it (such as `cellScrollView`) are returning **nil**. They are connected via `IBOutlet`. I have never had this happen to me before, the line where is error occurs is :

```
cell.cellScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((2 * cell.frame.size.width), cell.frame.size.height)
```

And the error is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Below is the ViewController..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    func random() -> CGFloat { return CGFloat(rand()) / CGFloat(RAND_MAX) }
    func randomColor() -> UIColor { return UIColor(red: random(), green: random(), blue: random(), alpha: 1.0) }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        var tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.registerClass(SnapchatTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

        scrollView.addSubview(tableView)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //TableView DataSource

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 80
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SnapchatTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        cell.cellScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((2 * cell.frame.size.width), cell.frame.size.height) //This is where the crash occurs, the error tells me cell.cellScrollView is nil

        return cell
    }


}
```

..and here is the class that inherits `UITableViewCell` and is the custom class of the cell in storyboard:

```
import UIKit

class SnapchatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var cellScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var colorView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    //ScrollViewDelegate

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `viewWithTag()` function in the storyboard instead of using outlets.

Give your cellScrollView a tag for example of 100 then simply call `cell.viewWithTag(100) as UIScrollView` to access your scroll view. Do the same for all subviews in your cell.

Comment: Why is that? Why can I not use IBOutlets in this case?

Comment: I am not sure... Maybe someone could shed some light on this? It may have some thing to do with the reuse of the cell where the content tags should stay with each instance, because the IB cell is only a prototype, so the outlets are not connected with each instance. But I am unsure...

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve my issue (object is still nil), thank you though